# VScode shows import error , can't import DAG

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, airflow, importerror

I am trying to write script for DAG. I have run docker-airflow and is running well up on browser through localhost. But, whenever i try to open a dag file in vscode, it shows the import error.

I have installed and setup airflow using docker and activated docker using celery executor.

Docker Container for airflow is running.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5zlC.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the VS Code settings so you can run with your Docker virtual environment:

Set `python.pythonPath": "path_to_your_docker_virtual_environment\python.exe"` at the JSON settings file and save it.

After you can configure you VS Code to run within your docker virtual environment. Install the package with `pip install apache-airflow` and it will run.

Answer (score 1):

The import error means that the editor cannot find the `airflow` Python module.

The docker Airflow setup you did has nothing to do with the locally installed Python modules. That Airflow is inside a docker container and is not available as a package to your Python installation.

To install the `airflow` module you can run

```
pip install apache-airflow
```

Although, make sure that you install the same module version as the Airflow version in your docker container. Otherwise you may encounter compatibility errors with your DAGs.

Comment: But i dont want to run airflow in local mode , i need a containerized one :)

Comment: @SudipAdhikari as Sergiy mentioned, your installation of airflow in docker is not related to the local installation via `pip`. The only reason you install the local version is that your IDE (that runs on the host, not in docker) can see the imports (the local imports). If your IDE was not warning you about the impossibility to import you would not need the local install. Try editing the DAGs with, say, notepad and you will see that everything works fine because notepad doe snot attempt to help you in your development.